# Nested collection using embeded classes in JPA and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a db view which returns a data-set as follows

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  customer_id  |  order_id | order_detail_id  | product_id  | product_name |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1          |    10     |    101           |    1011     | P1           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1          |    10     |    102           |    1012     | P2           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2          |    20     |    201           |    1011     | P1           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2          |    20     |    202           |    1012     | P2           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2          |    30     |    301           |    1011     | P1           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to upload it into an object graph as follows

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "vw_all_customers_with_orders")
public Class Customer { 
    protected String customerId;

    @ElementCollection
    protected Set<Order> orders;
 }

@Embeddable  
public Class Order {

    @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected String orderId;

    @ElementCollection
    protected Set<OrderItem> orderItems;
}

@Embeddable
public Class OrderItem{

    @Column(name = "order_detail_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected String orderDetailId;

    @ElementCollection
    protected Set<Product> products;
}

@Embeddable
public Class Product{

    @Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected String productId;
}
```

This dosent seem to work anyways. i'm using JPA2.1 with hibernate 4.3.7

Where am i wrong ?

Comment: what is the issue you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment because of my reputation is low. And i am not sure on my answer

Is it incomplete code. Because an Entity has always primary key but Customer does not have @ID.
And for embeddable object in Set we require another Table

```
@Entity
public class User {
   [...]
   public String getLastname() { ...}

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Addresses", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
   @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name="street1", column=@Column(name="fld_street"))
   })
   public Set<Address> getAddresses() { ... } 
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
   public String getStreet1() {...}
   [...]
}
```

Comment: yes it has @id annotation . i forgot . and also i dont have a seperate table for collection . all the data is coming through that one view

Answer (score 0):

Two entity objects should not have same primary key value and in your case customer_id has same value. From this view, we can not make entity object list. I tried same thing on store procedure. Store Procedure fire query on database then result send to entity object

@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = NamedQueryConstants.STORE_PROC_CA_AWS_HIT_WEB_BY_TOC,
        query = "SPGET_WEB_ACTIVE_USER :fromAccessDate,:endAccessDate,:activeDays,:accessType, :tocCode",
        resultClass = FgraCaHitWebInfo.class
        )

If I send same primary key for two entity, error come. and if If I send different primary key, error did not come.      I tried same thing on store procedure. Store Procedure fire query on database then result send to entity object

Comment: dude . you can treat the whole row as unique and as a primary key .. i guess you are not getting the point. See, I clearly understand your point but my problem is that i am getting that data from the data store using some complex db logic . now once i get it in the application i jus want to transform it to an object graph , serialize it to an DTO and jus send it across wire for consumers.

Comment: can you try this 
    List list = s.createSQLQuery("call view").setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(DTOClass.class)).list();
    DTOClass dto =(DTOClass) list.get(0);